# Pass an array of two column values to a query - SpringJDBC

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

How do I send the array of two column values to the where condition of a sql query? The values in 'in' condition are variable. See an example below.

```
select *
from table_a ncjp
where
  (ncjp.col_a,ncjp.col_b) in ((2855824,5),(2855824,6));
```

Comment: I don't believe there is any native support for that. You have to build SQL with dynamic number of `?` markers, and use positional arguments (flat array) on `query()` call.

Comment: @Andreas Ok. thankyou

Comment: I'm using string concatenation approach as my solution for now.

Answer (score -2):

The best way you can build this is by creating a function which returns the value on the index of that 2D array so im guesing something like this

```
public object getElementAt(object [] []arr, int a, b){
return arr[a,b];
}
```

and then you can do

```
select *
from table_a ncjp
where
  (ncjp.col_a,ncjp.col_b) in :x;
query.setParameter("x", getElementAt(arr,1,2));
```

Comment: That will not get the result OP is after.

Comment: @Andreas, throughout what i read , i think that some form of this is what the OP has requested, or some alteration of it! 

he might be after something else, but in the way i read the answer this is how I see it!

Comment: In the case where he wants to send all the values of the 2d array in the query, he will have to do some sort of loop to create the query string according to the values in the array!

Comment: Well, first, you code is not valid Java. Second, you only return one value from `getElementAt()`, which means that the result is `where (ncjp.col_a,ncjp.col_b) in ?`, which is not valid SQL, since right-hand side of `=` must be two values, or sets of two values. In short, your answer is misleading and not useful.

Comment: @Andreas, if the problem is there , the Op would have to do something like, `select * from table_a ncjp where (ncjp.col_a,ncjp.col_b) in :x,:y;`

And then set the parameters correctly! I was giving an example, not a solution